# Have I identified the IUPAC name of this ketone correctly?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

$\ce{(CH3)2-CH-CO-CH2-CH2-OH}$

The IUPAC name I came up with was **1-hydroxy-4-methyl-3-pentanone** because:

- Ketone has **higher priority** over alcohol
- The **lowest locant set** is achieved by numbering the C bonded to -OH group as 1.

But the answer given states it is *4-methyl-3-oxo-1-pentanol* which violates the first rule mentioned above.

Please clarify the discrepancy between my reasoning and the textbook answer.

Comment: I think you book has a few nomenclature mistakes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assessment is correct. According to the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069)*, the order of seniority of classes in decreasing order of seniority is as follows.

> (…)
>   16. Ketones
>   17. Hydroxy compounds (includes alcohols)
>   (…)

However, locants are placed immediately in front of the part of the name to which they refer. Therefore, the correct name for the compound that is given in the question is **1-hydroxy-4-methylpentan-3-one.**